# Exposing kubernetes service container running on my PC localhost via WLAN IP to enable connection from another PC with both PCs on the same router

Tags: kubernetes, ip, minikube, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a k8s service running on my PC locally and works fine.
The Database and the services. everything works fine and are accessible via localhost on my browser and postman.
However, I want to be able to connect to it via other PC/mobile app on the same router/internet.
So, I have tried port forwarding, and I've tried mapping using
***netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=8014 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=8014 connectaddress=172.18.xx.xx***
But no luck yet.
My question is that "Is this possible or am I just wasting my time?". I have spent up to 5 days on this already and I'm not sure if it is possible or not.
Please any lead or solution will be highly appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try listening on `127.0.0.1`, or completely remove the `listenaddress` which should make it default to `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although I've been able to resolve it since then. However, your answer is absolutely what worked for me back then. I just had to completely remove the `listenaddress` to ensure everything goes back to default and it worked.